# Запрет или отслеживание создания новой вкладки своего сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Есть мой сайт. Необходимо отслеживать создание/открытие новой вкладки данного сайта. И соответственно выводить сообщение, что уже есть открытая вкладка

Comment: Если у сайта не предусмотрены эти действия, то никак вы этого не сделаете, напрямую через `js` это сделать не удастся, если только аддон для браузера писать или попробовать найти на просторах, а иначе, просто забыть. Если сайт ваш и вы хотите сделать такое, то например через локальное хранилище записывать вкладку. а при повторных сравнивать и закрывать если уже есть такая вкладка.

Comment: @And Конечно же это мой сайт, я знаю что можно через куки сделать или через localStorage. Но каков алгоритм, как записать вкладку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var siteKey = 'isSiteOpened:' + location.host;
    if(localStorage.getItem(siteKey)) {
        $('html').remove();
        alert('Вкладка с этим сайтом уже открыта');
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(siteKey, true);
        $(window).unload(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem(siteKey);
        });
    }
});
```

Разумеется данный скрипт должен находиться на каждой странице сайта.